# Initializing Binded int Property Value in Caliburn does not map it to mahApps SplitButton SelectedIndex Property

Tags: caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro, data-binding, wpflocalizationextension

I'm initializing the value like this: (MahApps.Metro 1.1.3-ALPHA)

```
private int currentCulture;
public int CurrentCulture
{
    get { return currentCulture; }
    set
    {
        if (currentCulture != value)
        {
            currentCulture = value;
            LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = Languages[value];
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CurrentCulture);
        }
    }
}       

protected override void OnInitialize()
{
    base.OnInitialize();
    Languages.AddRange(BS.Expert.Client.App.Utils.Resources.GetAvailableCultures());
    CurrentCulture = Languages.IndexOf(new CultureInfo(LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture.Name));
    ...
```

The thing is that I'm not seeing the value set in the dropDown mahApps control when the view is launched..., what's going on?

```
<Controls:SplitButton
     Orientation="Horizontal"
     x:Name="Languages"
     cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action ChangeCulture($eventArgs)]"
     DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
     SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentCulture, ElementName=SplitButton0, Mode=TwoWay}" >
 </Controls:SplitButton>
```

Comment: hi, what version of MahApps do you using? cause this is maybe fixed with v1.1.2

Comment: MahApps.Metro 1.1.3-ALPHA